# JUnit class should have exactly one public constructor

Tags: java, junit

In VS Code got a specific Java project with the following JUnit test

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.Test;

class NgramTest {
    
    @Test 
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

If I run it, I get an initializationError saying

> java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public
> constructor

[image: Java Unit Test in VS Code]

What can be done to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write public before class NgramTest. Change the code to

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.Test;

public class NgramTest {
    
    @Test 
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

That way it'll work fine and you'll get, as expected, the result

> java.lang.AssertionError: Not yet implemented

[image: JUnit Test successful in VSCode]

Comment: Can we make it work with out the public modifier?

Comment: @AlekhyaReddy if you don't use any of the access modifiers it means you are using a default access modifier